# Chrome DevTools broken - Stetho unusable

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, okhttp, stetho

Stetho and Google Chrome DevTools have become unusable after a macOS update (I doubt that macOS update is the origin of this bug, but I prefer to mention it).

Here is the appearance of DevTools after the open of "inspect mode" on a device (provided by Facebook Stetho library for Android & OKHttp).

[image: DevTools window]

There are no longer "CSS" stylesheets on the page and fonts have changed.
Many tab pages aren't displayed (i.e. Network Requests), I only have access to some error messages :

```
There were 84 bytes that were not consumed while processing request 4
There were 84 bytes that were not consumed while processing request 5
There were 84 bytes that were not consumed while processing request 6
Failed to clear temp storage: undefined
```

I followed instructions on this issue : [Failed to clear temp storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358446/failed-to-clear-temp-storage/35172470) and this one : [Failed to clear temp storage: SecurityError in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850053/failed-to-clear-temp-storage-securityerror-in-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I haven't been able to fix the problem.

Here is what I tried :

- Uninstall and reinstall Chrome with AppCleaner
- Remove chrome cache from disk
- Remove chrome profiles from `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome`
- Create and use a new Chrome profile
- Try to connect on Firefox distant debug (unfonctionnal)
- Restart system

Have any of you ever encountered this problem ?
Thanks !

Comment: Same problem with chrome 89, gonna wait google for fixing it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should downgrade Chrome. Problem with the latest Chrome/Chromium release https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/696

Comment: Erf, I created a StackOverflow thread instead of an issue because no one of my colleagues had the bug... 
Thank you so much for your answer, I was able to fix this by downloading this version of Chromium : https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/827102/

Answer (score 19):

As a workaround you can use other browser based on Chromium, for example:

- **Microsoft Edge** https://www.microsoft.com/edge
- **Brave**  https://brave.com/

where you can also use `chrome://inspect/#devices` address to check your database content.

The biggest disadvantage at this moment is that you cannot view the shared preferences (which was possible on Chromium 88)

Comment: brave worked for me.I really wanted to install brave now I got a reason

Answer (score 0):

Until better solution is found you can download portable Google Chrome version 87.0.4280.88 and use it particularly for debugging. This way you don't need to downgrade your main Google Chrome app - you use both apps simultaneously.

`GoogleChromePortable_87.0.4280.88_online.paf.exe`

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/

Comment: i'd recommend to download chromium instead

Answer (score -1):

For those who want to avoid downgrading Chrome but still want to visualize their databases: Stetho is a great tool, but I've just discovered it's no longer a must-have thanks to improvements in Android Studio

In recent versions of Android studio it's possible to go to the <kbd>App Inspection</kbd> and then <kbd>Database Inspector</kbd> to do the same inspections and operations on Room databases as Stetho offers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this https://github.com/itkacher/OkHttpProfiler to check api and it's response like Stetho library in android studio.