# chrome inspect dev tools is not showing well (stetho for android)

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

I've been using chrome dev tools to see the android data base and preferences, I'm using stetho library, I have not gotten any issue until today, when I open the de tools it looks messy, I don't know how to fix it, any idea?

here a picture to show you how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Same here, I just published my app, while after that, I was checking for trying to API responses locally using stetho, but stetho dev tools started looking weird and showing this 
"1 message is hidden by filters."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome DevTools broken - Stetho unusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461857/chrome-devtools-broken-stetho-unusable)

Answer (score 1):

I found that Microsoft Edge works well now with Stetho. Google Chrome doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your google chrome to solve this problem!

This portable version could help you:

https://www.filehorse.com/download-google-chrome-portable-64/57166/download/#google_vignette